# How to append values to a key in ruby hashtag

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to append multiple values to the same key in a ruby hash. Have been using

```
    tags.merge!({'xyz': 'abc'})
```

to add new tags to the hash, however haven't been able to find a way to add multiple values to the same key.

For example:

```
  tags = {'square': 'blue', 'rectangle': 'green, 'circle': 'yellow'}
```

I want to add another color to a shape so it looks like:

```
  tags = {'square': 'blue', 'rectangle': 'green, 'circle': ['yellow','red']}
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Many possible solutions. If you *can* have multiple entries it's probably a better idea to *always* have an array as the value. You can automate that by having the default value be an array and push the new value(s) onto it.

Comment: Thanks Dave. However there are no built in functions that can be used to append values for a key?

Comment: No, there are no built in functions to do that. A hash key can reference only one value. That's why it might be helpful to always start out with an array for each value, initializing an empty one if the value is not yet set.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a block to [`merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) and do what you want with the values being merged in a duplicated key:

```
tags = {square: 'blue', rectangle: 'green', circle: 'yellow'}
tags.merge!({ circle: 'red', square: 'red' }) do |key, oldval, newval|
  if key == :circle
    # Change to array and add the new value
    (oldval.is_a?(Array) ? oldval : [oldval]) << newval
  else
    # Acts like default
    newval
  end
end

# => {:square=>"red", :rectangle=>"green", :circle=>["yellow", "red"]}
```

But it will be better if `:circle` is an array even with one element.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
tags = {'square' => 'blue', 'rectangle' => 'green', 'circle' => 'yellow'}

def add(hash, key, value)
    if hash[key]
        hash[key] = ([hash[key]] << value).flatten
    else
        hash[key] = value   
    end
    hash
end

p add(tags, 'circle', 'red')
#=> {"square"=>"blue", "rectangle"=>"green", "circle"=>["yellow", "red"]}

p add(tags, 'circle', 'violet')
#=> {"square"=>"blue", "rectangle"=>"green", "circle"=>["yellow", "red", "violet"]}
```

**Update:**
If the `value` in your hash is going to be an array always, then, something like below can be done

```
tags[key] = [[tags[key]] << value].flatten.compact
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys! I went with initializing an empty array for all the tag values and using ternary operator to append values to a specific key like this:

```
     tags.has_key?(:circle) ? (tags[:'circle'] << "#{row['shape']}") : (tags[:'circle'] = ["#{row['shape']}"])
```

I was using the data from a CSV file so it will write values from a specific row.

And used .uniq to remove duplicates.

Comment: `tags[:'circle'] << [row['shape'] ]`